# How to implement Python decorator with arguments as a class?

Tags: python, instance, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to implement a decorator which accepts some arguments. Usually decorators with arguments are implemented as double-nested closures, like this:

```
def mydecorator(param1, param2):
    # do something with params
    def wrapper(fn):
        def actual_decorator(actual_func_arg1, actual_func_arg2):
            print("I'm decorated!")

            return fn(actual_func_arg1, actual_func_arg2)

        return actual_decorator

    return wrapper
```

But personally I don't like such approach because it is very unreadable and difficult to understand.

So I ended up with this:

```
class jsonschema_validate(object):
    def __init__(self, schema):
        self._schema = schema

    def __call__(self, fn):
        self._fn = fn

        return self._decorator

    def _decorator(self, req, resp, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            jsonschema.validate(req.media, self._schema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
        except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
            _log.exception('Validation failed: %r', e)

            raise errors.HTTPBadRequest('Bad request')

        return self._fn(req, resp, *args, **kwargs)
```

The idea is very simple: at instantiation time we just captures decorator args, and at call time we capture decorated function and return decorator instance's method, which is bound. It is important it to be bound because at decorator's invocation time we want to access `self` with all information stored in it.

Then we use it on some class:

```
class MyResource(object):
    @jsonschema_validate(my_resource_schema)
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        pass
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work. The problem is that at decorator invocation time we looses context of decorated instance because at decoration time (when defining class) decorated method is not bound. Binding occurs later at attribute access time. But at this moment we already have decorator's bound method (`jsonschema_validate._decorator`) and `self` is passed implicitly, and it's value *isn't* `MyResource` instance, rather `jsonschema_validate` instance. And we *don't want to loose* this `self` value because we want to access it's attributes at decorator invocation time. In the end it results in `TypeError` when calling `self._fn(req, resp, *args, **kwargs)` with complains that "required positional argument 'resp' is missing" because passed in `req` arg becomes `MyResource.on_post` "`self`" and all arguments effectively "shifts".

So, is there a way implement decorator as a class rather than as a bunch of nested functions?

### Note

As my first attempt of implementing decorator as simple class was failed rather quickly, I immediately reverted to nested functions. It seems like properly implemented class approach is even more unreadable and tangled, but I want to find solution anyway for the fun of the thing.

### UPDATE

Finally found solution, see my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it!

As I wrote, the problem that a method can't have two `self`, so we need to capture both values in some way. *Descriptors* and *closures* to the rescue!

Here is complete example:

```
class decorator_with_args(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self._arg = arg

    def __call__(self, fn):
        self._fn = fn

        return self

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        def _decorator(self_, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f'decorated! arg: {self._arg}')

            return self._fn(self_, *args, **kwargs)

        return _decorator.__get__(instance, owner)
```

Let's break it down to pieces!

It starts exactly as my previous attempt. In `__init__` we just capture decorator arguments to it's private attribute(s).

Things get more interested in next part: a `__call__` method.

```
def __call__(self, fn):
    self._fn = fn

    return self
```

As before, we capture decorated method to decorator's private attribute. But then, instead of returning actual decorator method (`def _decorator` in previous example), we return `self`. So decorated method becomes instance of decorator. This is required to allow it to act as [*descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction). According to docs:

> a descriptor is an object attribute with "binding behavior"

Confusing, uh? Actually, it is easier than it looks. Descriptor is just an object with "magic" (dunder) methods which is assigned to another's object attribute. When you try to access this attribute, those dunder methods will be invoked with some calling convention. And we'll return to "binding behavior" a little bit later.

Let's look at the details.

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
```

Descriptor must implement at least `__get__` dunder (and `__set__` & `__delete__` optionally). This is called "descriptor protocol" (similar to "context manager protocol", "collection protocol" an so on).

```
    if instance is None:
        return self
```

This is by convention. When descriptor accessed on class rather than instance, it should return itself.

Next part is most interesting.

```
        def _decorator(self_, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f'decorated! arg: {self._arg}')

            return self._fn(self_, *args, **kwargs)

        return _decorator.__get__(instance, owner)
```

We need to capture decorator's `self` as well as decorated instance's `self` in some way. As we can't define function with two `self` (even if we can, Python couldn't understand us), so we *enclose* decorator's `self` with *closure* - an inner function. In this closure, we actually do alter behavior of decorated method (`print('decorated! arg: {self._arg}')`) and then call original one. Again, as there is already argument named `self`, we need to choose another name for instance's `self` - in this example I named it `self_`, but actually it is `self'` - "self prime" (kinda math humor).

```
        return _decorator.__get__(instance, owner)
```

And finally, usually, when we define closures, we just return it: `def inner(): pass; return inner`. But here we can't do that. Because of "binding behavior". What we need is returned closure to be *bound to decorated instance* in order it to work properly. Let me explain with an example.

```
class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        print(self)

Foo.foo
# <function Foo.foo at 0x7f5b1f56dcb0>
Foo().foo
# <bound method Foo.foo of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f5b1f586910>>
```

When you access method on class, it is just a *plain Python function*. What makes it *a method* instead is *binding*. Binding is an act of linking object's methods with instance which is passed implicitly as firs argument. By [convention](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods), it is called `self`, but roughly speaking this is not required. You can even store method in other variable and call it, and will still have reference to instance:

```
f = Foo()
f.foo()
# <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f5b1f5868d0>
other_foo = f.foo
other_foo()
# <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f5b1f5868d0>
```

So, we need to bind our returned closure to decorated instance. How to do that? Remember when we was looking at method? It could be something like that:

```
# <bound method Foo.foo of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f5b1f586910>>
```

Let's look at it's type:

```
type(f.foo)
# <class 'method'>
```

Wow! It actually even a class! Let's create it!

```
method()
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# NameError: name 'method' is not defined
```

Unfortunately, we can't do that directly. But, there is [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType):

```
types.MethodType
# <class 'method'>
```

Seems like we finally found what we wanted! But, actually, we *don't need to create method manually!*. All we need to do is to *delegate to standard mechanics of method creation*. And this is [how actually methods work](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) in Python - they are just *descriptors* which bind themselves to an instances when accessed as instance's attribute!

> To support method calls, functions include the `__get__()` method for binding methods during attribute access.

So, we need to just delegate binding machinery to function itself:

```
_decorator.__get__(instance, owner)
```

and get method with right binding!

Answer (score 2):

This is fun! Thanks for posting this question.

Writing a simple decorator that doesn't take arguments is pretty easy, but extending that to a class that then gets called three times is a bit more challenging. I opted to use a `functools.partial` to solve this problem.

```py
from functools import partial, update_wrapper
from unittest import TestCase, main


class SimpleDecorator(object):

    def __new__(cls, func, **params):
        self = super(SimpleDecorator, cls).__new__(cls)
        self.func = func
        self.params = params
        return update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        args, kwargs = self.before(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.after(self.func(*args, **kwargs))

    def after(self, value):
        return value

    def before(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return args, kwargs


class ParamsDecorator(SimpleDecorator):

    def __new__(cls, **params):
        return partial(super(ParamsDecorator, cls).__new__, cls, **params)


class DecoratorTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_simple_decorator(self):
        class TestSimpleDecorator(SimpleDecorator):

            def after(self, value):
                value *= 2
                return super().after(value)

        @TestSimpleDecorator
        def _test_simple_decorator(value):
            """Test simple decorator"""
            return value + 1

        self.assertEqual(_test_simple_decorator.__name__, '_test_simple_decorator')
        self.assertEqual(_test_simple_decorator.__doc__, 'Test simple decorator')
        self.assertEqual(_test_simple_decorator(1), 4)

    def test_params_decorator(self):
        class TestParamsDecorator(ParamsDecorator):

            def before(self, value, **kwargs):
                value *= self.params['factor']
                return super().before(value, **kwargs)

        @TestParamsDecorator(factor=3)
        def _test_params_decorator(value):
            """Test params decorator"""
            return value + 1

        self.assertEqual(_test_params_decorator.__name__, '_test_params_decorator')
        self.assertEqual(_test_params_decorator.__doc__, 'Test params decorator')
        self.assertEqual(_test_params_decorator(2), 7)
```

As you can see I've opted for a design with hooks for modifying the arguments and responses in methods. Hopefully, most of the time this would prevent needing to touch `__call__` or `__new__`.

I couldn't think of a way to attach `params` to `ParamsDecorator` after returning the `partial`, so I had to opt for putting it into the `SimpleDecorator` but not using it.

I think that this does a good job of keeping the content flat instead of nested. I also like that this can take care of `functools.wraps` for you so you shouldn't need to worry about including that on these decorators. The downside to writing a decorator this way is you're now introducing a new module that you would need to install or maintain and then import every time you write a decorator.