# How to implement "decorator" functionality in a "class" object?

Tags: python, class, object, stdout, decorator

**I'm trying to build a class that suppresses stdout and stderr.**  I have it down when used as a `with statement` but I want to extend the functionality to also be used as a decorator that I can use to suppress output on functions.  Is it possible to have everything completely contained within the class or does the wrapper need to be a function outside of the class?

I am attempting to follow these resources but it's difficult to adapt to my situation:

https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/

[How to implement Python decorator with arguments as a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013015/how-to-implement-python-decorator-with-arguments-as-a-class)

```
import os,sys, functools


class Suppress(object):
    def __init__(self, show_stdout=False, show_stderr=False):
        self.show_stdout = show_stdout
        self.show_stderr = show_stderr
        self.original_stdout = None
        self.original_stderr = None

    def __enter__(self):
        devnull = open(os.devnull, "w")

        # Suppress streams
        if not self.show_stdout:
            self.original_stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = devnull

        if not self.show_stderr:
            self.original_stderr = sys.stderr
            sys.stderr = devnull

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Restore streams
        if not self.show_stdout:
            sys.stdout = self.original_stdout

        if not self.show_stderr:
            sys.stderr = self.original_stderr


    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def decorator(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                with self(*args, **kwargs):
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
         return decorator



with Suppress(show_stdout=False, show_stderr=False):
    print("stdout", file=sys.stdout)
    print("stderr", file=sys.stderr)
```

**I am trying to also have this functionality as a decorator:**

```
@Suppress(show_stdout=True)
def f(x, y):
    print(x, file=sys.stdout)
    print(y, file=sys.stderr)
    return x*y
a = f(1,2)
# 1
# a = 2
```

I had a similar decorator working (though, very ugly) for a `matplotlib` style wrapper.  However, this had to use an outside function and was not within a class.

```
# # Decorators
# def stylize(style="seaborn-white"):
#     def decorator(func):
#         @functools.wraps(func)
#         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
#             with plt.style.context(style):
#                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
#         return wrapper
#     return decorator
# # Wrappers
# def subplots_wrapper(style="seaborn-white", *args, **kwargs):
#     @stylize(style)
#     def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
#         return plt.subplots(*args, **kwargs)
#     return inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can't you just define `__call__ ()` on the class and put your decorator code there?

Comment: There is `contextlib.ContextDecorator` that you may want to inherit from.

Comment: `contextlib` also supplies `redirect_stdout` and `redirect_stderr` managers.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I've updated the __call__ method but I now get: `TypeError: decorator() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: @chepner I did not realize that! I'm checking this out now. https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html  .  I should probably redo my code so it uses contextlib instead.

Comment: @chepner I tried using contextlib but I couldn't figure it out. https://pastebin.com/raw/Da3amR0m

Comment: It's tricky, but short. See my answer.

Comment: @chepner wow, i will definitely need to unpack that a bit.  it's much different than i'm used to.  thanks for taking the time to do that.  i will definitely try to understand this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use simply `with self` without arguments:

```
   def __call__(self, function):

        @functools.wraps(function)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
```

Comment: So close...but so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can define this by combining various pieces from `contextlib`. In short, this uses `ExitStack` to compose the requested redirection context managers into a single context manager, and `ContextDecorator` to use the resulting context manager as a decorator as well.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack, ContextDecorator, redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr
import sys
from os import devnull


class Suppress(ContextDecorator, ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, show_stdout=False, show_stderr=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.redirections = []
        if show_stdout:
            self.redirections.append(redirect_stdout)
        if show_stderr:
            self.redirections.append(redirect_stderr)

    def __enter__(self):
        rv = super().__enter__()

        if self.redirections:
            f = rv.enter_context(open(devnull, "w"))
            for r in self.redirections:
                rv.enter_context(r(f))
        return rv
```

`__init__` stores the classes `redirect_stdout` and `redirect_stderr` that will be necessary in a list.

`__enter__`, if any redirections were requested, opens the appropriate sink and makes the appropriate redirections. As an exit stack, `Suppress` will take care of ensure that the redirections are ended and the sink will be closed.